# Reevaluate the prompt expression each time a prompt is displayed in zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt, variable-substitution

I'm adjusting my zsh prompt, based upon the [dallas](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/dallas.zsh-theme) theme and the [dstufft](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/dstufft.zsh-theme) theme from [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). I love how dallas has various sections of the prompt contained in variables, which makes it much easier to understand what's going on.

The problem is, these strings are evaluated *once* for expansion. So when I attempt to use something dynamic, such as the `${PWD/#$HOME/~}` of dstufft, then it no longer updates dynamically.

How can I get the best of both worlds? I'd like the prompt broken up into subsections that are evaluated each time the prompt gets written.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure that the [`prompt_subst` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST) is turned on. If necessary, add the following line to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
setopt prompt_subst
```

This tells zsh to reevaluate the prompt string each time it's displaying a prompt. Then, make sure you are assigning `PS1` (or some other variable that is used by the prompt theme) as desired:

```
PS1='${PWD/#$HOME/~}'
```

The single quotes protect the special characters such as `$` from being evaluated when you set the variable.

Comment: Oh duh! I can't believe I was using double quotes instead of single quotes. Too much Windoze...

Comment: god, thanks, I've been debugging for hours, and indeed, double quotes...

Answer (score 6):

In zsh, `precmd` can do anything (such as setting a variable) before each prompt:

```
function precmd() {
    current_git_branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
}
```

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html

This isn't so necessary for the current directory as in the original question, but may be helpful for people who find this question for other cases.

(precmd is zsh-only — in bash, there is `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.)

Comment: if you are using oh-my-zsh, do not name your function `precmd()`, but different, e.g. `extra_precmd()` 

and add a

`precmd_functions+=extra_precmd`

in your `~/.zshrc` somewhere after the having sourced `oh-my-zsh.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

I just need to escape my `$` signs. For example:

```
${PWD/#$HOME/~}
\${PWD/#\$HOME/~}
```

Comment: Why isn't this answer upvoted more? Worked for me in `zsh`, much easier than other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In zsh you should use `%` escapes for this. For example, instead of `${PWD/#$HOME/~}` (as your example), just use `%~`.

Read `zshall(1)` and look for **SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES** (it's too long to quote here).

Comment: I'm following Steve's approach [here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/). You can see the issue that `%~` brings up. I'm also running some functions in the prompt.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun `unsetopt cdable_vars` would solve the issue of environment variables creeping into `%~`.