# Reload zsh when resizing terminator window

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, gnome-terminator

I'm using terminator with zsh in combination with antigen. The theme (a modified version of af-magic) I'm using retrieves the current window width and prints a bar consisting of `=` signs to separate inputs.

```
# af-magic.zsh-theme
# Repo: https://github.com/andyfleming/oh-my-zsh
# Direct Link: https://github.com/andyfleming/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/af-magic.zsh-theme

if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then NCOLOR="red"; else NCOLOR="green"; fi
local return_code="%(?..%{$fg[red]%}%? ↵%{$reset_color%})"

# primary prompt

BAR=$(printf '=%.0s' {1..$(tput cols)})

PROMPT='$FG[237]$BAR%{$reset_color%}
$FG[032]%~\
$(git_prompt_info) \
$FG[105]%(!.#.»)%{$reset_color%} '
PROMPT2='%{$fg[red]%}\ %{$reset_color%}'
RPS1='${return_code}'


# color vars
eval my_gray='$FG[237]'
eval my_orange='$FG[214]'

# right prompt
if type "virtualenv_prompt_info" > /dev/null
then
    RPROMPT='$(virtualenv_prompt_info)$my_gray%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%'
else
    RPROMPT='$my_gray%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%'
fi

# git settings
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="$FG[075](branch:"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="$my_orange*%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="$FG[075])%{$reset_color%}"
# af-magic.zsh-theme
# Repo: https://github.com/andyfleming/oh-my-zsh
# Direct Link: https://github.com/andyfleming/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/af-magic.zsh-theme

if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then NCOLOR="red"; else NCOLOR="green"; fi
local return_code="%(?..%{$fg[red]%}%? ↵%{$reset_color%})"

# primary prompt

BAR=$(printf '=%.0s' {1..$(tput cols)})

PROMPT='$FG[237]$BAR%{$reset_color%}
$FG[032]%~\
$(git_prompt_info) \
$FG[105]%(!.#.»)%{$reset_color%} '
PROMPT2='%{$fg[red]%}\ %{$reset_color%}'
RPS1='${return_code}'


# color vars
eval my_gray='$FG[237]'
eval my_orange='$FG[214]'

# right prompt
if type "virtualenv_prompt_info" > /dev/null
then
    RPROMPT='$(virtualenv_prompt_info)$my_gray%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%'
else
    RPROMPT='$my_gray%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%'
fi

# git settings
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="$FG[075](branch:"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="$my_orange*%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="$FG[075])%{$reset_color%}"
```

This works pretty well, but when resizing the window the `BAR` is not updated and so it's either too short or too long, taking multiple lines. Example:

```
|==================================================================|
|~ »                                                               |
```

becomes

```
|==================================================| 
|================                                  | <- window border
|~ »                                               |
```

Is there a way to make either zsh or terminator reload the theme upon resizing the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the terminal is resized, the shell receives a [SIGWINCH](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html#index-SIGWINCH) signal. So update `BAR` in a trap. In zsh you can define the corresponding [trap function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Trap-Functions):

```
TRAPWINCH () {
  BAR=$(printf '=%.0s' {1..$COLUMNS})
}
```

You don't need to call `tput` since zsh tracks the number of columns of the terminal in the [`COLUMNS` variable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-COLUMNS).

Make sure to turn on the [`prompt_subst`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST) option (`setopt prompt_subst`) so that `$PROMPT` is reevaluated each time it's displayed. Alternatively, update `PROMPT` in `TRAPWINCH` as well.

Instead of forking to call `printf` in a strange way, you can use [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) to get a padded string. Parameter expansion normally works from the value of a variable, but `${:-STRING}` lets you work from a string instead, in this case an empty string. This way you don't need a trap at all.

```
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='$FG[237]${(l:$COLUMNS::=:):-}%{$reset_color%}
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40595/reevaluate-the-prompt-expression-each-time-a-prompt-is-displayed-in-zsh):

Make sure that the `prompt_subst` [option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST) is turned on. If necessary, add the following line to your `~/.zshrc`:

`setopt prompt_subst`

**This tells zsh to reevaluate the prompt string each time it's displaying a prompt**.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I'll update my question to include the complete theme

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn $BAR into a function:

```
function bar {
    echo `printf '=%.0s' {1..$(tput cols)}`
}
```